# Generate QR code to special page

Tags: php, qr-code

I have qr code that generate code to my website www.myweb.com. But I want to customize : If visitor website generate code from QR code use smartphone it will redirect to www.myweb.com/qr.php. This the algorithm scheme:

```
If visitor website -> QR code
   redirect to www.myweb.com/qr.php
Else
   redirect to www.myweb.com
```

Any trick for that on PHP language, without change my QR code because I have already print on all collateral, like sticker, card name, etc ? I have search but not find yet.

Comment: What is `User`? Are you insinuating your QR code's link is `http://qr:password@www.myweb.com`?

Comment: @lc. web visitor that I mean, I already have clear my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the link from the QR code is simply `www.myweb.com`, I'm afraid you are out of luck. There is absolutely no difference between reading a QR code and accessing the link and manually typing in the address.

The only possibility is you *may* be able to catch certain visitors *if* they are using an app to read the QR code, subsequently view the target page in-app, *and said app has something identifiable about it's User Agent string*. I have not experimented with this, but I would suspect this is actually *not* the case.

Comment: I can't, I want to tricky out of my PHP code not app or qr code

Comment: My point is *if* the app has an identifiable User Agent, you could catch this from PHP. Otherwise you *can't* do what you suggest.